# C++ - Remove duplicates from a sorted vector of structs

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, struct, duplicates

I have a structure as shown below.

```
struct Num {
    uint64_t key;
    uint64_t val;
};

// Compare based on their key and value.
bool num_less(Num a, Num b)
{
    if(a.key < b.key)
        return true;
    else if(a.key == b.key)
    {
        if(a.val < b.val)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
    else
        return false;
}

// Compare based on their key and value.
bool num_equal(Num a, Num b)
{
    return ((a.key == b.key) && (a.val == b.val)) ? true : false;
}
```

I have a vector of structs. I want to remove the duplicates from that vector. I tried the following approach.

1. Sort the vector
2. Remove the duplicates(consecutively placed)

   `vector<Num> arr;`

   `sort(arr.begin(), arr.end(), num_less);`

   `arr.erase(std::unique(arr.begin(), arr.end(), num_less);, arr.end());`

But when I run the above code, only the first element of the sorted vector is printed and rest of them are somehow deleted. I am not sure what am I doing wrong.

Edit - I tried with num_equal function in `std::unique`. And it worked.

Comment: You need to provide an overloaded equality operator `operator==` for your struct.

Comment: Actually I added the num_equal function in `std::unique`. But it didn't work.

Comment: From http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/unique, the 3rd argument is a "binary predicate which returns ​true if the elements should be treated as equal." So you should use num_equal instead of num_less.

Comment: Rule of thumb: only use the constants `true` and `false` to initialise variables, and never elsewhere. Your test are terribly convoluted, you can just write `return a.val < b.val;` instead of `if (a.val < b.val) return true; else return false;`, for instance. The whole first function should be written as `return (a.key < b.key) or (a.key == b.key and a.val < b.val);` Equivalently, the second would be `return (a.key == b.key) and (a.val == b.val);`

Comment: Try to use a std::set instead of std::vector.

Comment: Unfortunately I am not allowed to use std::set or std::sort in my use case. Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: `num_less);,` - ahem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to define equal predicate

```
struct Num 
{
    unsigned int key;
    unsigned int val;
};

bool num_less(const Num &a, const Num &b)
{
    return (a.key<b.key)||(!(b.key < a.key))&&(a.val<b.val));
}
bool num_equal(const Num &a, const Num &b)
{
    return (a.key==b.key)&&(a.val==b.val);
}
int main()
{
    vector<Num> arr;
    Num temp;
    // add some examples
    temp.key=10; temp.val=20;
    arr.push_back(temp);        arr.push_back(temp);
    temp.key=11; temp.val=23;
    arr.push_back(temp);        arr.push_back(temp);
    temp.key=10; temp.val=20;
    arr.push_back(temp);        arr.push_back(temp);    arr.push_back(temp);
    //sort
    sort(arr.begin(),arr.end(),num_less);
    //delete dublicates
    arr.erase(unique(arr.begin(),arr.end(),num_equal),arr.end());
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your `num_less` is wrong and can be rewritten correctly as `return std::tie(a.key, a.val) < std::tie(b.key, b.val);`

Comment: you are right it is num_great, but the code works correctly, because of it deletes all dublicats.

Comment: Yeah, my num_less was messed up. I changed it and it's working fine now.

Comment: @h.o.m.a.n: currently, your `num_less` is equivalent to `(a.key < b.key) ||(a.val < b.val)`, so `{1, 2} < {2, 1}` but also `{2, 1} < {1, 2}`...

Comment: @Jarod42 i usually use [link](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/utility/pair/operators/) "operator <" like the standard to write any less function

Comment: So you have a typo in `!(a.key < b.key)` which should be `!(b.key < a.key)`.